# Getting SSL Exception with trying upload to AWS s3

Tags: android, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I get this error, when try to upload a picture on my Android app. This is the first time I'm working with AWS.

```
Unable to execute HTTP request: Write error: ssl=0x9f025e00: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x9f025e00: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
```

I have create a Account, a Bucket, a Cognito Identity Pool.

```
public class SaveProfilePictureOnAWSS3 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            String picture_url = params[0];

            // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
            CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    App.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), // Application Context
                    App.getInstance().getResources().getString(R.string.AWS_IdentityPoolId), // Identity Pool ID
                    Regions.EU_WEST_1 // Region enum
            );

            AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);

            File fileToUpload = new File(picture_url);

            PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest("millezimu", MilleZimU.getInstance().getUserInstance().getId(), fileToUpload);
            PutObjectResult putResponse = s3Client.putObject(putRequest);



        } catch (Exception e) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageToDisplayEvent(e.getMessage(), true));
        }


        return null;
    }
```

or with this :

```
TransferUtility transferUtility = AWSUtils.getTransferUtility(MilleZimU.getInstance());
TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload("millezimu",
    MilleZimU.getInstance().getUserInstance().getId(), fileToUpload);
```

but still get the error !

Comment: Please provide code to reproduce and the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happen because the region of the client was not set !!!

After adding the region to the helper provided in Amazon Demo, it works.

```
/**
 * Gets an instance of a S3 client which is constructed using the given
 * Context.
 *
 * @param context An Context instance.
 * @return A default S3 client.
 */
public static AmazonS3Client getS3Client(Context context) {
    if (sS3Client == null) {
        sS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(getCredProvider(context.getApplicationContext()));
        sS3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1));
    }
    return sS3Client;
}
```

Comment: Glad that you resolve the problem, but odd that region causes SSL issue.